# Add domain on fields.Reference

Tags: python, odoo

I want to a add a domain on a fields.Reference.

```
class CategoryWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'category.wizard'

    _description = 'Category Tree Manipulation'

    tree1_type = fields.Reference(selection=[('product.public.category', 'Website Category Tree'), ('product.category', 'Internal Category Tree')],
                                  string="First Tree", domain="['parent_id', '=', False]")

    tree2_type = fields.Reference(selection=[('product.public.category', 'WebSite Category Tree'), ('product.category', 'Internal Category Tree')],
                                  string="Second Tree")
```

In my example i want only to show the Category Tree Head with the `domain="['parent_id', '=', False]")` after selecting the Model

Answer (score 0):

In odoo domain is List of tuple , every tuple have 3 elements `(field_name, operator, value)`  :

```py
     domain="[('parent_id', '=', False)]"
```